# Cannot add server reference: Contract requires Duplex, but Binding 'BasicHttpBinding' doesn't support it or isn't configured properly to support it

Tags: c#, wcf

I am making a WCF Service application on localhost and am having trouble with adding a service reference to a client application (in the same Visual Studio solution)

I am getting an error which says: "Contract requires Duplex, but Binding 'BasicHttpBinding' doesn't support it or isn't configured properly to support it." when I try to add the service reference. I am also able to start the service and it opens my browser automatically. From that point clicking on ScadaService.svc shows the same error.

When I change the service name to [ProjectName].ScadaService I get a different error, which says that there is no endpoint listening at 'http://localhost:11303/ScadaService.svc/$metadata'.

I have pasted my entire code in a new project class by class with no success.

The only contract that doesn't have a callback function has basicHttpBinding and changing it to wsDualHttpBinding does not work.

Web.config file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="Service1">
        <endpoint address="RealTimeUnit" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="Commons.ServiceContracts.IRTUService"/>
        <endpoint address="RealTimeUnit/Mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
        <endpoint address="DatabaseManager" binding="wsDualHttpBinding" contract="Commons.ServiceContracts.IDatabaseService"/>
        <endpoint address="DatabaseManager/Mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
        <endpoint address="Trending" binding="wsDualHttpBinding" contract="Commons.ServiceContracts.ITrendingService"/>
        <endpoint address="Trending/Mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
        <endpoint address="AlarmDisplay" binding="wsDualHttpBinding" contract="Commons.ServiceContracts.IAlarmService"/>
        <endpoint address="AlarmDisplay/Mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Service contracts:

```
[ServiceContract(CallbackContract = typeof(IAlarmCallback))]
public interface IAlarmService
{
    [OperationContract]
    void AlarmInit();
}
[ServiceContract]
public interface IAlarmCallback
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void RaiseAlarm(Tag tag, double value);
}

[ServiceContract(CallbackContract = typeof(IDatabaseCallback))]
public interface IDatabaseService
{
    [OperationContract]
    void DatabaseInit();

    [OperationContract]
    void AddSimulationUnit(int address, SignalType signalType, int scanPeriod);

    [OperationContract]
    void RemoveSimulationUnit(int index);

    [OperationContract]
    void AddTag(Tag tag);

    [OperationContract]
    void ModifyTag(string tagId, Tag newTag);

    [OperationContract]
    void RemoveTag(string tagId);
}
[ServiceContract]
public interface IDatabaseCallback
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void GetTags(List<Tag> tags);

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void TagAdded(Tag tag);

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void TagModified(string tagId, Tag newTag);

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void TagRemoved(string tagId);
}

[DataContract]
public enum SignalType
{
    [EnumMember] Sine,
    [EnumMember] Cosine,
    [EnumMember] Ramp,
    [EnumMember] Triangular,
    [EnumMember] Rectangular,
    [EnumMember] Digital
}

[ServiceContract]
public interface IRTUService
{
    [OperationContract]
    void RTUInit(string iD, string publicKeyPath);

    [OperationContract]
    void RTUDelete(string iD, byte[] signature);

    [OperationContract]
    void RTScan(int address, double value, string iD, byte[] signature);
}

[ServiceContract(CallbackContract = typeof(ITrendingCallback))]
public interface ITrendingService
{
    [OperationContract]
    void InitTrending();
}

[ServiceContract]
public interface ITrendingCallback
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void GetTags(List<Tag> tags);

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void TagAdded(Tag tag);

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void TagModified(string tagId, Tag newTag);

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void TagRemoved(string tagId);

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void NewScan(string tagId, double value);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure whether it could help, but the only problem I meet with your code is that duplicate OperationName. I couldn't reproduce your problem, after I change the OperationName , I could add reference to the service.

In addition, I remove your enum type SignalType and replace it with int.

Below is my contract.

```
[DataContract]
public class Tag
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
[ServiceContract(CallbackContract = typeof(IAlarmCallback))]
public interface IAlarmService
{
    [OperationContract]
    void AlarmInit();
}
[ServiceContract]
public interface IAlarmCallback
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void RaiseAlarm(Tag tag, double value);
}

[ServiceContract(CallbackContract = typeof(IDatabaseCallback))]
public interface IDatabaseService
{
    [OperationContract]
    void DatabaseInit();

    [OperationContract]
    void AddSimulationUnit(int address, int signalType, int scanPeriod);

    [OperationContract]
    void RemoveSimulationUnit(int index);

    [OperationContract]
    void AddTag(Tag tag);

    [OperationContract]
    void ModifyTag(string tagId, Tag newTag);

    [OperationContract]
    void RemoveTag(string tagId);
}
[ServiceContract]
public interface IDatabaseCallback
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void GetTags(List<Tag> tags);

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void TagAdded(Tag tag);

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void TagModified(string tagId, Tag newTag);

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void TagRemoved(string tagId);
}

[ServiceContract]
public interface IRTUService
{
    [OperationContract]
    void RTUInit(string iD, string publicKeyPath);

    [OperationContract]
    void RTUDelete(string iD, byte[] signature);

    [OperationContract]
    void RTScan(int address, double value, string iD, byte[] signature);
}

[ServiceContract(CallbackContract = typeof(ITrendingCallback))]
public interface ITrendingService
{
    [OperationContract]
    void InitTrending();
}

[ServiceContract]
public interface ITrendingCallback
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true,Name = "TrendGetTags")]
    void GetTags(List<Tag> tags);

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true, Name = "TrendTagAdd")]
    void TagAdded(Tag tag);

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true, Name = "TrendTagModified")]
    void TagModified(string tagId, Tag newTag);

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true, Name = "TrendTagRemoved")]
    void TagRemoved(string tagId);

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true, Name = "TrendNewScan")] // change the operation name
    void NewScan(string tagId, double value);
}
```

My service is empty.

```
 public class ScadaService : IRTUService,IDatabaseService,ITrendingService,IAlarmService
{
    public void AddSimulationUnit(int address, int signalType, int scanPeriod)
    {

    }

   // ignore other method


}
```

My svc

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="Service.callback.ScadaService"  %>
```

My web.config.The same Metaservicebehavior with yours

```
  <service name="Service.callback.ScadaService">
    <endpoint address="RealTimeUnit" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="ServiceInterface.callback.IRTUService"/>
    <endpoint address="RealTimeUnit/Mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
    <endpoint address="DatabaseManager" binding="wsDualHttpBinding" contract="ServiceInterface.callback.IDatabaseService"/>
    <endpoint address="DatabaseManager/Mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
    <endpoint address="Trending" binding="wsDualHttpBinding" contract="ServiceInterface.callback.ITrendingService"/>
    <endpoint address="Trending/Mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
    <endpoint address="AlarmDisplay" binding="wsDualHttpBinding" contract="ServiceInterface.callback.IAlarmService"/>
    <endpoint address="AlarmDisplay/Mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
  </service>
```

Comment: The problems were with the identical operation names. Changing them and service name to "[ProjectName].ScadaService" fixed the bug.

Thank you for the help.